# Bundle.preferredLocalizations confusion

Tags: ios, localization, nsbundle

The 3 `preferredLocalizations` of `Bundle` are so confusing that I have so many questions:

1. Why the 2 `preferredLocalizations` methods are class methods but keep talking about some *unspecified* specific bundle as if they are called on some individual `Bundle` instance?

   - [`preferredLocalizations(from:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/bundle/1417249-preferredlocalizations): What exactly are `a bundle object` and `the bundle`?

     1. > Returns one or more localizations from the specified list that **a bundle object** would use to locate resources for the current user.
     2. > An array of NSString objects, each of which specifies the language ID for a localization that **the bundle** supports.
   - [`preferred​Localizations(from:​for​Preferences:​)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/bundle/1409418-preferredlocalizations): What exactly are `the specified bundle` and `the receiver’s bundle`?

     1. > Returns the localizations that a bundle object would prefer, given **the specified bundle** and user’s language preferences.
     2. > An array of NSString objects, each of which identifies a localization in **the receiver’s bundle**. These strings are ordered in the array according to the specified preferences and are taken from the strings in the localizations​Array parameter. If none of the user-preferred localizations are available in the bundle, this method returns one of the bundle localizations.
2. Why `preferredLocalizations(from: localizations)` does't return the same result as `preferred​Localizations(from: localizations, ​for​Preferences:​ nil)`? As noted above reading their docs doesn't really help. Sure they look designed this way but actually not:

   ```
   // Locale.preferredLanguages: ["es-CN", "ja-CN", "zh-Hans-CN", "en-CN", "he-IL"].
   let localizations = ["de", "en", "es", "fr", "it"]
   print(Bundle.preferredLocalizations(from: localizations)) // ["en"]
   print(Bundle.preferredLocalizations(from: localizations, forPreferences: nil)) // ["es"]
   ```

Answer (score 4):

The reference documentation isn't that great; [Technical Note 2418](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2418/_index.html) explains it better.

Specifically, it says

> Note that Bundle.preferredLocalizations(from:) will restrict the results to localizations supported by Bundle.mainBundle(), or the return value of Bundle.mainBundle().localizations(). If you would like to match against a different set of language identifiers, use Bundle.preferredLocalizations(from:forPreferences:) which does not rely on mainBundle’s localizations and instead solely relies on the two arguments passed in.

So,

- If you use `Bundle.preferredLocalizations(from:)`, the localizations list you give it is first filtered against the localizations defined for the main bundle (`Bundle.main.localizations`).
- If you use `Bundle.preferredLocalizations(from:forPreferences:)`, it works with the list you give it.

In the example you gave, `Bundle.preferredLocalizations(from: localizations)` returns `["en"]`. This is likely because your app does not have any version of Spanish ("es") defined. If you add a Spanish localization to your project, it should return `["es"]`, since "es-CN" is listed before "en-CN".